# openX targeting channel setup ("OR"-functionality)

Tags: channel, openx, targeting

I have a site that uses OpenX for banner delivery. I want a banner that shows up when people are in a sports section of my site, so only when people are on

```
site.com/football
site.com/baseball
```

I set up a targeting channel for that which only shows banners when the site Page URL contains "football baseball". I use the iframe version of the invocation code. My zone has either football or baseball in it this works. But when I enter "football baseball" or "football,baseball" it doesn't work.

A workaround could be to have a new limitation rule for each of the keywords, but somehow there must be an "or" functionality in there, or am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways you should be able to handle this.

1. Create multiple delivery limitations (as you mentioned). In the Targeting Channel or directly in the Delivery tab for the banner, when you "Add" multiple limitations there should be a drop down in between each limitation allowing you to specify the an operator `AND` or `OR`. The benefit of setting this up as a Targeting Channel is that you can create complex groupings of limitations that aren't possible at the banner level alone.
2. The other option you could try is using "Regex match". When you select the Delivery Limitation of "Site - Page URL", instead of selecting contains you can select "Regex match". This should allow you to specify a value similar to `football|baseball` or something more complex.

Comment: That is the path I was looking in to indeed (your 2nd option). It's not very well documented through. Right now I use the first option, but that's not very readable. Do you know the exact syntax for a regexp banner?

Comment: It should be any valid PHP regex. It can be something as simple as that in the answer above or something more complex (albeit contrived) like `[bf]\w{3,5}ball|golf|soccer` to match basketball, baseball, football, golf or soccer.